# What to do If you can't clean a place that you made dirty

Tags: salat, sin, jannah, jahannam, deeds

What should you do If you cant' clean a place that you made unclean?
If you for example step with your dirty shoes on a carpet or maybe put your dirty shoes on a chairseat but are unable to clean it because you can't enter that place anymore. I am scared that someone puts their hand or clothes  on that place where I put my dirty shoe and that they get dirty and when they are going to pray their salah is unvalied because they touched dirt. What should I do I can't clean that place, should I make dua?

Answer (score 2):

Not everything dirty is considered Najis. And if there is no Najis under the shoes, there is no problem with his prayer if he touches them. Even if a place is Najis and someone who does not know touches it, their prayer is still valid.

Also, if you cannot clean there, at least inform the owner or people there so they can clean it. the questions should be cleared more but if the place or thing that has became Najis is usually used for prayer or some action that being Najis makes that action invalid so you should inform the owner. otherwise not necessary to inform.

If something Najis touches the carpet, it can be cleaned by pouring water on it several times and collecting the water.

Comment: What if the owner doesn't want to clean it?

Comment: Or instead of contacting the owner  can I make dua for them?

Comment: You also said if someone doesn't know a place is najis and they touches it their salah is still vaild. But let's say their is a very visable spot on the floor and you touche it,but you don't see it dispite it is very visible is the prayer still valid because you still didn't see it but you touched it?

Comment: @dill if the place or thing that has became Najis is usually used for prayer or some action that being Najis makes that action invalid so you should inform the owner. if owner did not want ro clean it then there is nothing on you and you have done your duty. about your last comment anyway if someone is not aware or sure about becoming Najis so there is no problem and his prayer is valid. even if someone has doubt about Najis still prayer is valid. if something is visible but one is not sure what it is so it is doubt and prayer is valid. for example I see a yellow liquid so I am not sure

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can I make dua just in case I might punished for having made something najis or is it just waswas because I have very much anxiety over it?

Comment: @dill if it has been unintentional so it has no punishment. and you always can make dua for forgiveness of all sins.

Comment: Is saliva najis, i know that dogs salivia is najis, if someone  touches someone elses (human) saliva does it make your prayer invalid or does it break your wudu?

Comment: @dill human saliva is not Najis. but dogs salliva is najis

Comment: I have one more question, what if someone touches a dirty place While taking wudu but the person don't know it is dirty or have not seen the dirt?

Comment: @dill no problem. only if you are sure your body or cloth became Najis then you should make it pure.